# Element that follows user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created an element(image div) called 'bunny', an input form and a fieldset. I also have a localhost web server which runs my websocket server for my chat. I'm trying to implement a function where for every message(which are spans) sent, the bunny element is placed beside each message.

***The problems I've encountered doing this are:***

- Since the messages are span, the bunny element duplicates itself and is appended to each span instead of just the end of the message.
- The bunny element doesn't sit exactly beside the message, it is usually below the span on a new line, I've tried appendTo and InsertAfter in JS

**HTML:**

```
<div id="bunny">
</div>

<input id="message" type="text" />
<button type="button" id="movebunny">Bunny</button>

<fieldset id="showMsg" >
<!--messages are shown here-->
</fieldset>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var messages;
var form;
var inputBox;

function log_msg(msg) {
  messages.appendChild(document.createElement("span")).innerHTML = msg;
} 

function doInit() {
  inputBox = document.getElementById("message");
  messages = document.getElementById("messages");
  form = document.getElementById("message-form");
  var s;
  ...
```

*//there's a bit more to the js code but they're all just to connect to server//*

Would greatly appreciate any suggestions to getting element at the end of each message sent on click of a button, thanks!

Comment: got a picture of what you mean? Because the textual description is not quite clear enough

Comment: Yeh sure, have a look at these two: http://prntscr.com/4mgmv0 & http://prntscr.com/4mgngc

Comment: Can you show the produced HTML after displaying some messages? And CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really kind of need to show more code, too, or create a jsfiddle but without additional context: just use a different skeleton (note that fieldset is not being truthful about what's in it. A field set is for form fields. You're using it to wrap inert messages):

```
<div class="messages">
  <div class="message">
    <div class="from sender">bob</div>
    <div class="body">blahblahblah</div<
  </div>
  <div class="message">
    <div class="from listener">carol</div>
    <div class="body">blahblahblah</div<
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

and every time you get a new message, you `appendChild` it to the `.messages` div, and then move (not copy) the `bunny` element into the last message. You get something like

```
<div class="messages">
  ...
  <div class="message">
    <div class="from">carol</div>
    <div class="body">blahblahblah</div<
    <div class="bunny">^_^</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you use CSS to make sure the bunny's in the right place.

```
div.messages { position: relative; }
.from.listener { float: left; position: relative; }
.from.sender { float: right; position: relative; }
.bunny { width: ...; height: ...; background: url('bunny.png'); }
.from.listener .bunny { position: absolute; left: 0}
.from.sender .bunny { position: absolute; right: 0}
.hidden { display: none!important; }
```

With your bunny element all the way at the top, before there are any messages:

```
<div class="hidden bunny">^_^</div>
```

And you just move the bunny down by using

```
var bunny = document.querySelector(".bunny");
```

all the way at the start so you have a persistent reference, and then every time you build a new message

```
var newmsg = ....;
bunny.classList.remove("hidden");
newmsg.appendChild(bunny);
messages.appendChild(newmsg);
```

done, `appendChild` moves elements across the page (because DOM elements can't exist in two places at once, so an appendChild of an on-page element simply moves it to its new position).

Comment: Just wanted to thank you, haven't tried it out yet but it makes sense. Appreciate it!